# How to set maximum year option of the year spinner of com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

I'm using com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser popup in my application and need to set the maximum year option of the year spinner.

Comment: *"need to set the maximum year"*  Why? Did you book ahead for an apocalypse?

Comment: I'm sorry if something wrong with my question. I have found the answer of my question. dateChooser.getJCalendar().getYearChooser().setMaximum(2014);

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188), but you may want to update the question to reflect the answer.

Comment: OK. The question has updated